# Recaptcah V3 Site key Exceed Limitation

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Google Recaptcha V3 has a service limit quota of **1000 calls/second** or **1 Million requests/month** for the **free tier**. else if the application exceeds these limits then google Sends a warning to the site owner to migrate to Recaptcha V3 Enterprise.

I've checked the Recaptcha V3 admin panel and it shows some analytics, one of the analytics is **"Total requests"** and it shows I had around **2 Million requests** received.

My questions :

1. Does the analytics shown in the Recaptcha V3 admin panel are for requests made using the **site_key** *(to get valid captcha token)* or using the **Secret_key** *(to validate captcha token)* of reCaptcha?
2. does the service limit that google warned me about are regarding the requests made using the **Site_key** of the **Secret_key**?
3. If the answer to the previous question is **"Site_key"**, then is not it possible for a malicious user to get the **site_key** from my site and use it maliciously to request for valid captcha token thus I'll exceed my Recaptcha site limits, How to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this, if you or anyone has found anything? And also do failed calls against the validate api call count towards the usage? If so a malicious user could just bombard your endpoint that calls the google verify endpoint and exhaust the limits

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/pricing, the limitations are the same for 4 kinds of requests:

- assessments.create
- password.check (If a password check is passed along with an assessment, 2 calls are counted)
- siteverify
- Token verification
  (for Google Cloud Armor)

So looks like "requests made using the site_key (to get valid captcha token)" are "assessments.create". And requests that are "using the Secret_key (to validate captcha token)" are password.check.

So both kinds of requests are under same limit, and both are counted as one request each, so 2 requests total per flow of getting captcha and submitting it.

Comment: so, a malicious can, indeed, abuse your site key to make go over your quota.

Comment: Unless you protect from too many requests somehow - limit by IP etc.